# How to show a new image every x seconds?

Tags: javascript

Trying to do a set Interval timer using JavaScript, I'm not sure how to put images in a array.
I have tried several different ways but can't get it to work.

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = [img class="irc_mi ix3z7xWjrSdc-pQOPx8XEepE" alt="Image result for baseball images" style="margin-top: 70px;" src="http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" width="626" height="415",
img class="irc_mi ix3z7xWjrSdc-pQOPx8XEepE" alt="Image result for baseball images" style="margin-top: 70px;" src="http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" width="626" height="415",
img class="irc_mi ix3z7xWjrSdc-pQOPx8XEepE" alt="Image result for baseball images" style="margin-top: 70px;" src="http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" width="626" height="415"]

var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {
    myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
  indexImage = 0;
  }
}

setInterval(changeImage,5000);
```

thanks in advance, also I'm new and did try to look for an answer but could not find one.

Comment: Your `imageArray` isn't a valid array. You basically have a giant syntax error between the `[` and the `]`. Based on your code, you only need to have the sources  in the array: `var imageArray = [ "http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg", "...", "..." ];`

Comment: And `imageIndex !== indexImage`

Answer (score 2):

Several things

1. Your array needs to be an array of strings:
2. You're setting the src attribute to an entire string that consists of more than the source
3. indexImage isn't defined

   ```
   var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

   var imageArray = [
       "http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg",
       "http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg",
       "http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg"
   ]

   var imageIndex = 0;

   function changeImage() {
       myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
       imageIndex++;
       if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
           imageIndex = 0;
       }
   }

   setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
   ```

Comment: Just replace the closing `}` with a closing `]` under the imageArray definition

Comment: Edited. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

first it's not negative comment but,You just can't throw what ever you want into the array. They can hold strings,numbers,func,obj,...

- Since all other variables are same first create a static image as

```html
<img id="mainImage"  class="irc_mi ix3z7xWjrSdc-pQOPx8XEepE" alt="Image result for baseball images" style="margin-top: 70px;" onload="google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" width="626" height="415"/>
```

- modify your array as

  var imageArray=["http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg","http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg","http://totalsportscomplex.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/baseball-pic.jpg"]

```js
  function changeImage() {
        myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
      imageIndex++;
      if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
      indexImage = 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for all the help, I did not take it as negative appreciate the help. I was not sure how to put image in array. I still cant get my image to show up but the timer works. It gives me the alt so I'm still missing something.